# Changing order of Double Summation

Tags: summation, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I'm working in the following problem in the Bishop book - Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning:

[image]

I read the solution and there was a trick to prove twice of the double summation of the anti-symmetric term as zero:

[image]

I do not understand the last three lines of the solution. How does this transformation hold?
$$
\sum^D_{i=1}\sum^D_{j=1}w^A_{ji}x_ix_j = \sum^D_{j=1}\sum^D_{i=1}w^A_{ji}x_jx_i
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^D\left(w_{ij}^A+w_{ij}^A\right)x_ix_j
&=\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^D\left(w_{ij}^A-w_{ji}^A\right)x_ix_j\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^Dw_{ij}^Ax_ix_j-\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^Dw_{ji}^Ax_ix_j\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^Dw_{ij}^Ax_ix_j-\sum_{j=1}^D\sum_{i=1}^Dw_{ji}^Ax_jx_i\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^Dw_{ij}^Ax_ix_j-\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=1}^Dw_{ij}^Ax_ix_j}\tag{4}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the antisymmetry property $w_{ij}^A=-w_{ji}^A$ with $1\leq i,j\leq D$.
- In (2) we multiply out.
- In (3) we reorder the terms of the right-hand double sum by exchanging the sums. We also use commutativity $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$.
- In (4) we add an intermediate step by *substituting* in the right-hand double sum $i$ with $j$ and also $j$ with $i$. The last line follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in changing the order of double summation. Try to visualize it with a matrix, if you sum all the coefficients row by row and then you sum the results it is the same thing as summing line by line then summing the results.

For instance,

$$(a_{1,1}+ a_{1,2}) + (a_{2,1} +a_{2,2})+(a_{3,1}+a_{3,2}) = (a_{1,1}+ a_{2,1}+a_{3,1}) +(a_{1,2}+ a_{2,2}+a_{3,2})$$